# PHP Windows Environment Variable for A Script

Tags: php, windows

In **windows** is there a way to **symlink** as you would in linux?

If put put a file inside `/usr/bin` called sample I can access it via:

```
$ sample
```

In Windows I have PHP in my Environment variables so I can just run:

```
$ php filename.php
```

**This doesn't work. bit I'd like it to**. I tried placing my script inside the Windows Environment variables and running it through php, eg:

```
$ php sample
```

But it only works when i do

```
$ php c:/path/sample

or

$ cd c:/path/sample
$ php sample
```

Does anyone know? :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link

Answer (score 1):

Because /usr/bin is in PATH, and C:/path seems to be not in.
Or I not understood the question?